# Compile C - Windows

Tags: c, windows

I am wanting a simple way to compile Windows Console Applications in C. I am doing cross-platform development for university, and copying things into Microsoft VS to compile for Windows, and then using cygwin for *nix compilation is just too tedious.

If anyone has a simpler solution, maybe a way to compile with a makefile in cmd (if so please provide resources for *simple* windows make files) then that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cygwin doesn't do unix compilation (at least, none of the compilers that come packaged with it, although it is possible to build a cross compiler).  It does Windows compilation from unix source code.  If you have code that compiles with gcc, and you have cygwin gcc on your Windows box and gcc on your Unix box, then you don't need Visual Studio at all.

Comment: I see! So I would just need to make a "windows makefile" for it to compile the source code using the _WIN32 definition? (as my source code files are broken up with `#ifdef _WIN32 ... #else ... #endif`)

Comment: When compiling with Cygwin gcc, the `_WIN32` macro will be true, the compiler automatically predefines it.  So if you have for example (on multiple lines of course) `#if _WIN32 #include <windows.h> #else #include <curses.h> #endif` then your cygwin build will take the Win32 path and your Unix build will take the else.  And you can use the same Makefile and GNU make on both, if you install the appropriate packages in cygwin and your Unix or Linux package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check out mingw-64 to write portable C code for Windows and Unix.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW

The read up on cross compiling with cmake

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling